# using size_type of vector in map

Tags: c++, c++11

```
using line_nm = vector<string>::size_type;
map<string, set<line_nm>> m;
```

On the above code, why can't I use the code below?

```
map<string, set<vector<int>>> m1;
```

Test:

```
string str;
word[str].insert(5);
```

I got an error when I am using "m1" version.

Comment: What is the actual error?? And where and how is `word` declared?

Comment: Your question's not very clear, but perhaps you meant to simplify the first version to a one-liner?  If so, it should be: `map<string, set<vector<string>::size_type>> m1;`.

Comment: thank you, but what's the difference between vector<string>::size_type and vector<string>?

Comment: If you'd bothered reading any documentation you'd have realized that's a ridiculous question. You're basically asking what the difference between `size_t` and `vector<string>` is.

Comment: You are trying to insert a `5` into a `set` that is expecting a `vector`.

Comment: *"what's the difference between `vector<string>::size_type` and `vector<string>`?"* - `vector<string>` is the `vector` template instantiation for storing `string`s (i.e. an object of that type can store a number of `string`s), and one of the things that class contains is a `size_type` type definition - very likely something like `typedef size_t size_type;` - that you can use to create variables to store `size_type` values returned by `std::string::` member functions such as `.find()`.  If you don't know that, how'd you manage to write the `using line_nm = ...` code above, or isn't it yours?

Answer (score 4):

`vector<string>::size_type` is an integral type.

Hence,

```
map<string, set<line_nm>> m;
```

is analogous to:

```
map<string, set<size_t>> m;
```

`m[str]` returns a reference to a `set<size_t>`, whose `insert()` method is expecting a `size_t`. That's why you can use:

```
m[str].insert(5);
```

When you use:

```
map<string, set<vector<int>>> m1;
```

`m1[str]` returns a reference to a `set<vector<int>>`, whose `insert()` method is expecting a `vector<int>`, not an `int`. That's why you cannot use:

```
m1[str].insert(5);
```

you can use

```
m1[str].insert(arg);
```

where `arg` is a `vector<int>` or something which can be converted to a `vector<int>`.

```
m1[str].insert(std::vector<int>{5, 10, 30});
```